# ERROR IN CELEB-A dataset DOWNLOAD BY tensorflow_datasets

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to download CELEB-A by tensorflow_datasets (version: 4.5.2) and getting an API error. How can I fix it?
I have update the tensorflow_datasets but the issue does does not fix.
My code is:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tf ds
dataset_builder = tfds.builder('celeb_a')
dataset_builder.download_and_prepare()
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Downloading and preparing dataset 1.38 GiB (download: 1.38 GiB, generated: 1.62 GiB, total: 3.00 GiB) to /root/tensorflow_datasets/celeb_a/2.0.1...
Dl Size...: 0 MiB [00:00, ? MiB/s]                                                                                                                             | 0/4 [00:00<?, ? url/s]
Dl Completed...:   0%|                                                                                                                                         | 0/4 [00:00<?, ? url/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_datasets/core/dataset_builder.py", line 464, in download_and_prepare
    download_config=download_config,
  File "/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_datasets/core/dataset_builder.py", line 1158, in _download_and_prepare
    dl_manager, **optional_pipeline_kwargs)
  File "/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_datasets/image/celeba.py", line 129, in _split_generators
    "landmarks_celeba": LANDMARKS_DATA,
  File "/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_datasets/core/download/download_manager.py", line 549, in download
    return _map_promise(self._download, url_or_urls)
  File "/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_datasets/core/download/download_manager.py", line 767, in _map_promise
    res = tf.nest.map_structure(lambda p: p.get(), all_promises)  # Wait promises
  File "/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py", line 867, in map_structure
    structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
  File "/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py", line 867, in <listcomp>
    structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
  File "/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_datasets/core/download/download_manager.py", line 767, in <lambda>
    res = tf.nest.map_structure(lambda p: p.get(), all_promises)  # Wait promises
  File "/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/promise/promise.py", line 512, in get
    return self._target_settled_value(_raise=True)
  File "/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/promise/promise.py", line 516, in _target_settled_value
    return self._target()._settled_value(_raise)
  File "/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/promise/promise.py", line 226, in _settled_value
    reraise(type(raise_val), raise_val, self._traceback)
  File "/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/six.py", line 703, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/promise/promise.py", line 844, in handle_future_result
    resolve(future.result())
  File "/miniconda/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 428, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/miniconda/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/miniconda/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 57, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_datasets/core/download/downloader.py", line 216, in _sync_download
    with _open_url(url, verify=verify) as (response, iter_content):
  File "/miniconda/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py", line 112, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_datasets/core/download/downloader.py", line 276, in _open_with_requests
    url = _get_drive_url(url, session)
  File "/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_datasets/core/download/downloader.py", line 298, in _get_drive_url
    _assert_status(response)
  File "/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_datasets/core/download/downloader.py", line 310, in _assert_status
    response.url, response.status_code))
tensorflow_datasets.core.download.downloader.DownloadError: Failed to get url https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B7EVK8r0v71pZjFTYXZWM3FlRnM. HTTP code: 404.
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the link is broken hence this error is shown while fetching this `celeb_a` tensorflow dataset. However you can download this dataset manually using this [link](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B7EVK8r0v71pZjFTYXZWM3FlRnM) till we fix that error, .